# Javascript .push causing array to nest deeper and deeper

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm sure this is an easy one, however my searches haven't helped as of yet.

When I push an array into another array, they nest a level deeper. The first array is at the correct depth.

```
var productArray = [{productID: currentProduct, productPrice: currentPrice, productName: productName, options: myOptions}];

if(localStorage.getItem("cart")){
    var existingArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
    existingArray.push(productArray);
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(existingArray));
} else {
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(productArray));
}
```

Result:

```
0: Object { productID: "1", productPrice: "2.00", productName: "Chicken Sandwich", … }
​
1: 0: Object { productID: "1", productPrice: "2.00", productName: "Chicken Sandwich", … }
​
2: 0: Object { productID: "1", productPrice: "2.00", productName: "Chicken Sandwich", … }
```

Comment: That's what's *supposed* to happen, why did you expect otherwise?

Comment: Rather than `push`ing the array into the other, you should be concatenating (using [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) or [`...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), for example).

Comment: @jonrsharpe From the 2nd array onwards, the array is 1 level deeper.

Comment: `existingArray.push(...productArray)` or  for internet exploder, `existingArray.push.apply(existingArray, productArray)`

Comment: @TylerRoper I will try ..., concat is not working. It is not throwing any errors, however the new array does not get merged.

Comment: @M_Becker `concat` does not modify either of the arrays; it returns a *new* array. You'd likely want to store that as a new variable, ie `var newArray = array1.concat(array2)`, where `newArray` is the merged result of `array1` and `array2`.

Comment: @TylerRoper ... worked. I learnt something new today, thank you! Would you like to submit it as an answer so I can mark it as resolved?

Comment: @M_Becker I appreciate it - glad I could help. I believe this question likely falls under a handful of potential duplicates, so perhaps you can accept one of the suggested dupes and point future readers there instead :)

Comment: @TylerRoper Will do, thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options to concatenate two arrays, but `.push` is not it (unless you iterate the 2nd array and push each element individually, OR followup with `.flat()`)

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3];

array.push([4, 5, 6]);
console.log(array); // [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]

array = array.concat([7, 8, 9]);
console.log(array); // [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6], 7, 8, 9]

array = [...array, ...[10, 11, 12]];
console.log(array); // [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6], 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

array.push(13, 14, 15);
array = array.flat();
console.log(array); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Comment: Hey Junvar. In the future, consider marking duplicates rather than answering them. Submitting answers to questions that have already been asked a whole lot tends to clutter up the site with repeated information, and encourages users to ask repeat questions :)

Answer (score 0):

Because *productArray* is an array, and not an object, pushing it into another array will create *another* array, which will contain both, the initial array, and the new one.

To do what you were expecting, you should declare a new object, and push *it* into the existing array.

```
var productObject = {productID: 1, productPrice: 1, productName: '', options:{}};
var productArray = [];
if(localStorage.getItem("cart")){
    var existingArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
    existingArray.push(productObject );
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(existingArray));
} else {
    productArray.push(productObject);
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(productArray));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are adding the entire "productArray" in the position n of your "existingArray". Try to make this.

```
var productArray = [{productID: currentProduct, productPrice: currentPrice, productName: productName, options: myOptions}];

if(localStorage.getItem("cart")){
    var existingArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
    productArray.forEach(function(val){
     existingArray.push(val);
    })
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(existingArray));
} else {
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(productArray));
}
```